# How can I delete an app on docusign Apps and API page?

Tags: docusignapi

I created some apps on docusign "Apps and Keyd" page for testing using my demo developer account. Now I want to delete some of those apps but there is no option of deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there's no delete option.

Just rename old integration keys to "old" or somesuch. And delete all their secrets and key pairs.

Or use one for your next project.

Comment: Thanks @Larry, but its really annoying to see many useless apps there which we are not using but thanks for the confirmation.